# Nesting rows with conditional filter function

Tags: r, shiny, dt, reactable

I would like to create a table with hidden nesting rows that can be expanded based on a given column(s) that also works with the conditional filter system of DT shiny.

I would like the nesting to look like the reactable package grouping/aggregation https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#grouping-and-aggregation but retain the flexibility and utility of the DT package.

What is the best way to go about this?